# Error message on button click needed

Tags: jquery, button, radio-button

I have been given an assignment to which a user must select a university campus and click the proceed button. The only thing I cannot get working is that when there is no radio button selected and the proceed button is clicked there is supposed to be an error message that states '*You have not selected a university campus, please try again.*'

I have everything else working but this error code. I just can't seem to get it. There is a error message that appears stating 'Undefined,' which is coming from the click function for the button. Can someone help?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        input, label { line-height: 1.5em; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="university" value="Ah, we are not on the same site" id="Belfast">
            <label for="Belfast">Belfast</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="university" value="Yeah, we are on the same campus" id="Jordanstown">
            <label for="Jordanstown">Jordanstown</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="university" value="Ah, we are not on the same site" id="Coleraine">
            <label for="Coleraine">Coleraine</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="university" value="Ah, we are not on the same site" id="Magee">
            <label for="Magee">Magee</label>
        </div>
        <div id="log"></div>
    </form>

    <input type="button" value="Continue" id="click">
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#click").click(function () {
            alert($("input[type=radio]:checked").val());
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If there is no radio button selected there is no element whose value should be returned. This should explain the alert. As for preventing the submission, look into the `event` object that you get as an argument to your callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/VMLg9/

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    my_val = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();

    if( my_val === undefined){
        alert("MY_VALIDATION_ERROR");
    } else {
        alert($("input[type=radio]:checked").val());
    }

})
```

Comment: You absolute legend. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("input[type=radio]:checked").val()` try checking for length, like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#click").click(function(){
        if ($("input[type=radio]:checked").length == 0) {
            alert( 'Your message goes here' );
        }
    })
});
```

When you used `.val()` jQuery pulls the value of the selected radio button. Since no radio button is selected you get `undefined`. If you use `.length` jQuery returns the number of elements matching your selector string. In this case if none are checked you'll get a 0.